What is the normal procedure of z3 handle axiom with quantifier?
I've read some part of this book, this tutorial, and this tutorial, and would like to find out how Z3 handles quantified formula.
No matter with the book or in the web, it would like to map the term (that have a value in first order logic) in the quantified formula that contains quantified variables to existing term in E-graph (equivalence classes) to instantiate it.
Then I would have the following questions:

What if the E-graph is empty, which means all the formulas are quantified

Satisfiability of a set of first order formulas need to try all possible models, which is actually infinite.


My understanding is:

Before anything, we need to do skolemization to all functions, which eliminate existing quantifier and make all quantified formula to form of $\forall x_1,...,x_n \phi (x_1,...,x_n)$

Treat all non-quantified variables in formula as new constant symbols. If there is no such variable, then instantiate 1 new constant symbol

Apply the matching procedures to match variables with these new constant symbols, update E-graph, and keep instantiate until find a conflict or satisfactions occurs.


If a satisfactions arise, we can conclude:

Since all variables are instantiated by constant symbol, then a model correspond to the constant symbol should be applied

With step 1 and E-graph, we can build up a limited model that satisfy the formulas


Thus the set of formula is satisfiable.
If a conflict arise, we can conclude:

Since the instantiation is corresponding to constant expanded symbols, thus all of the replacements with constant symbol can be proved (by first order theorem) with the global axiom of specialization, thus the conflict are proved to be exsist

With the above step and godels completeness theorem, the set of formulas cannot be satisfied by any model


I don't know if the above logic is correct and applied in Z3, one of the evidence that I found is that Z3 will loop with those formulas with infinite constant instantiations (e.g. Peano Arithmetic Axioms).
Furthermore, reading Z3's code is pretty challenging and I cannot find a clue of how and why it process like this. Would there be any help on code reading of Z3?

This is a good paper to read: https://leodemoura.github.io/files/ematching.pdf. Your question is hard-to-answer since there're many parts to it, and stack-overflow is really about coding. I'd recommend asking one-question at a time, and perhaps trying https://cs.stackexchange.com

@alias The e-matching procedure is only for searching instantiations of quantified variables, which has the most relation about the current functions. What I'm asking is if this is done then what we do to determine satisable or not
